# cannot make inheritance work with super in module

Tags: python

I have read about new way to call ancestor's constructor via `super(..).__init__()` and wanted to use it. I have a directory dataset with three files: `__init__.py`

```
from .Dataset import Dataset
from .CSVDataset import CSVDataset
```

`CSVDataset.py`

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from dataset import Dataset


class CSVDataset(Dataset):
    """
    reads dataset from csv file
    """
    def __init__(self, file):
        Dataset.__init__(self)
        #super(CSVDataset, self).__init__()
        reader = csv.reader(open(file, 'r'), delimiter=',')
        x = list(reader)
        self.container = np.array(x).astype('double')
```

and `Dataset.py`. When I use it from `../dataset` like this

```
from dataset import CSVDataset
data = CSVDataset('test/data1')
```

it works only with `Dataset.__init__(self)`. It should work with `super(CSVDataset, self).__init__()` but it does not. Why is that?

update: I get error

```
>>> data = CSVDataset('test/data1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "dataset/CSVDataset.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(CSVDataset, self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Dataset draft:

```
class Dataset(Iterable):
    """
    base class representing dataset API.
    Remember, dataset is used for learning.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = None
        self.counter = None
    ....

class Iterable:
    def __iter__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            label = self[self.counter]
            self.counter += 1
            return label
        except:
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Your version with `super()` looks correct to me. What error message do you get?

Comment: Can you please include the definition of `class Dataset` too? Presumably this is Python 2?

Comment: Right, the exception tells you that `Dataset` is an old-style class, not a new-style unified type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Dataset` class is a Python 2.x *old style class*. `super()` only works on [*new style classes*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), where the class hierarchy ultimately inherits from `object`.

To fix, make `Dataset` inherit from `object`:

```
class Dataset(object):
```

Also see [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)